# SMTP Email Id parsing with single quotes surrounded - Is it valid?

Tags: email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to parse email id headers eg: To: <'test@domain.com'>,hello@world.com
Though the single quote around the email address is valid per SMTP RFC, when I parse, is it valid to strip of surrounding single quote (not the quotes in between if any).  It makes sense to remove, but I want to do the correct thing, not looking for beautifying and this email id is for storage purpose only and not sending emails.  I did a search and can't find anywhere that removing the quote is correct or wrong.  Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: Who generates such an address? While it seems valid syntactically (because the [`dot-atom` rule](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-3.2.3) allows apostrophes), `domain.com'` is not an Internet domain name, as required [later on](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-3.4.1).

Comment: @KasparEtter - Outlook does this for some of the cases, i dont have control as these are inbound to me..  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0fe4c269-8381-4324-9c48-2ca6b1d4e3c8/single-quotes-around-external-email-addresses?forum=outlook#:~:text=The%20single%20quotes%20mean%20that,t%20be%20any%20single%20quotes.

Comment: I see. In my opinion, this practice violates the relevant RFCs. Why do you think it is valid? I would probably strip the single quotes in order to have a unique representation. However, I would do so only if there are single quotes on both ends. Having a single quote in the local part is valid, and local parts should be interpreted/normalized only by the system denoted in the domain part. In other words, stripping a single quote at the beginning of the local part might invalidate an otherwise valid address.

Comment: Thanks @KasparEtter for the insights.  May be the approach could be if there are single quote at both ends then can be understood it could be an outlook issue or something like that but if there is only a quote in the local part then use it as-is..